# Why can't I find "read&tn=" in a String?

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-studio, instr

```
    Dim urlString As String
    Dim posn As Integer

    urlString = WebBrowser1.Url.ToString
    If urlString = "https://bookscan.cojc.org/bookscan/scan/trackingForm?read" Then ... works
```

But when I try to find "read&tn=" and I know that the full URL is
**https://bookscan.cojc.org/bookscan/scan/trackingForm?read&tn=409359

```
    posn = InStr("read&tn=", urlString, CompareMethod.Text)
    If posn > 0 Then .... is never true
```

Comment: Look closely at [the order of parameters to `InStr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.instr?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Yes, I had the parameters in the wrong order. That change made it work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As you know now, you had the parameters of `InStr` in the wrong order. How about not using the old VB6 `InStr` and updating to the .net `IndexOf` method.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s = "https://bookscan.cojc.org/bookscan/scan/trackingForm?read&tn=409359"
    Dim i = s.IndexOf("read&tn=")
    MessageBox.Show(i.ToString)
End Sub
```

Comment: Or even the `.Contains` method

Comment: @CaiusJard Yes, I wanted to point out the one to one replacement for 'InStr' but Contains will work just as well. Op's code was using the returned Integer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to interpret your url/pull bits out of it and make decisions based on its contents you might be better off parsing it

```
Dim qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri(urlString).Query)
```

`qs` will be a NameValueCollection with the key/value pairs in the url. If a key is present twice the value becomes a CSV string

```
Dim tn = qs("tn")
```

For your url, your `tn` variable now contains `"409359"`